# Keras Tokenization (fit on text)

Tags: machine-learning, keras, tokenize, keras-layer, stringtokenizer

When i am running this script-->

```
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(df['text'].values)
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(df['text'].values)
word_index = tokenizer.word_index
print('Found %s unique tokens.' % len(word_index))
```

I am getting this error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-4-7c08b89b116a> in <module>()
  ----> 1 tokenizer.fit_on_texts(df['text'].values)
        2 sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(df['text'].values)
        3 word_index = tokenizer.word_index
        4 print('Found %s unique tokens.' % len(word_index))

 /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/text.py in 
 fit_on_texts(self, texts)
     220                                             self.filters,
     221                                             self.lower,
 --> 222                                             self.split)
     223             for w in seq:
     224                 if w in self.word_counts:

 /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/text.py in 
 text_to_word_sequence(text, filters, lower, split)
      41     """
      42     if lower:
 ---> 43         text = text.lower()
      44 
      45     if sys.version_info < (3,):

 AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

My size of CSV file is 6970963 when I reduce the size it works, is there any size limit of keras Tokenizer or I am doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

I guess file size is not the issue, try using a try block and look at the data your are passing. Use some thing like this instead of the line

```
#instead of this
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(df['text'].values)

#use this to look at the data when it is causing that error.
try:
   tokenizer.fit_on_texts(df['text'].values)
except Exception as e:
   print("exceiption is", e)
   print("data passedin ", df['text'].values)
```

Then you can accordingly fix the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Check the datatype of the text you are fitting the tokenizer on. It sees it as a float instead of string. You need to convert to string before fitting a tokenizer on it. 
Try something like this: 
    train_x = [str(x[1]) for x in train_x]

Answer (score 0):

Although it is an old thread, but still following could be answer.

You data may have nan, which are interpreted as a float instead of nan. either force the type as str(word) or remove the nan using data.fillna('empty')